# Retrieving the correct .json for wunderground

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-requests

So far I have produced the following code:

```
import requests

def weatherSearch():
    Search = raw_input('Enter your location: ')
    r = requests.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/a8c3e5ce8970ae66/conditions/q/{}.json".format(Search))
    weatherData = r.json()
    print weatherData

weatherSearch()
```

For example, if `Search` was set to `London`, it would produce:

http://api.wunderground.com/api/a8c3e5ce8970ae66/conditions/q/London.json

However, this .json doesn't contain the temperature which is what I'm trying to find: `"temp_c":`

Whereas on the following link, `"temp_c":` can be found:

http://api.wunderground.com/api/a8c3e5ce8970ae66/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json

I'm struggling to understand what I'm doing wrong in order to retrieve the weather data.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your query returns a list of possible matches, each of which has an `l` key which contains a link. Using that link brings you back the full data for that location. So, for instance, the full data for London, UK is at http://api.wunderground.com/api/a8c3e5ce8970ae66/conditions/q/zmw:00000.1.03772.json.